# Pasting onto multiple sheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I have a macro which currently looks at an array, removes duplicates from the array and creates a list containing the remaining values. The macro then takes the values in this list and inserts a new worksheet within the Excel file for each entry (please see below)

```
Sub List_creator()

Sheets("ALL Scheme Derivatives").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$64944").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "A - Mini", "B - Supermini", "C - Lower Medium", "D - Upper Medium", _
    "E - Executive", "G - Specialist Sports", "H - MPV", "I - 4 x 4", "Y - LCV", "="), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("List").Select
Sheets("List").Name = "List"
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$1047980").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlNo


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Ki As Range
Dim ListSh As Range

With Worksheets("List")
    Set ListSh = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
End With

On Error Resume Next
For Each Ki In ListSh
    If Len(Trim(Ki.Value)) > 0 Then
        If Len(Worksheets(Ki.Value).Name) = 0 Then
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Ki.Value
         ActiveSheet.[a1] = ActiveSheet.Name
        End If
    End If
Next Ki

End Sub
```

For each of the newly created worksheets I have some items which I wish to paste in. This data needs to be pasted in to cell A2, and is currently stored as a template in a worksheet named 'Helper' in cells A2:M91. How can I amend my VBA to perform this additional task? Thank you.

EDIT: Gipadm your answer is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each Ki In ListSh
    If Len(Trim(Ki.Value)) > 0 Then
        If Len(Worksheets(Ki.Value).Name) = 0 Then
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Ki.Value
            ActiveSheet.[a1] = ActiveSheet.Name
            'Copy from sheet Helper
            Sheets("Helper").Range("A2:M91").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
        End If
    End If
Next Ki
```

Comment: A follow up from this, which I would be grateful if you could also help with! Once the above macro has pasted in the data, Column C of the pasted in data will contain either a string of text, or a dash ("-"). Is there a way I can amend my code so it will delete the first row which has a "-" in column C, and all other rows below it on that worksheet? Thank you once again for your time